# twitter sharing button bit.ly integration on a static website

Tags: javascript, html, url-shortener, bit.ly

I am trying to integrate bit.ly on my website in JS to short my url. All my url are too long, what will be the most straight foward way to use the bit.ly restful api for sharing button on a static website in HTML/javascript.

The result I want to get is when my user click share on my website the url is automatically shortened by bit.ly

here is the code I am currently using to share my pages dynamically on twitter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://bit.ly/javascript-api.js?version=latest&login=LOGINID&apiKey=APIKEY"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

function tweetCurrentPage()
      { window.open("https://twitter.com/share?url=" + escape(window.location.href) + "&text=" + document.title, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600'); return false; }

var TweetThisLink = {

    shorten : function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('http:',5))
        BitlyClient.shorten(url, 'TweetThisLink.response');
    },

    response : function(data) {
        var bitly_link = null;
        for (var r in data.results) {
            bitly_link = data.results[r]['shortUrl']; 
            break;
        }
        var tweet_text = "I am reading documentation of"
        document.location = "http://twitter.com/share?url=" + encodeURIComponent(tweet_text + ' ' + bitly_link);
    }
}


jQuery('.tweetlink').bind('click', TweetThisLink.shorten);
</script>

<a href="javascript:tweetCurrentPage()" class="tweetlink">tweet this link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is on purposefully obfuscated for the sake of the question, but 
In your script tag the src is:
"http://bit.ly/javascript-api.js?version=latest&login=LOGINID&apiKey=APIKEY".

LOGINID & apiKey are placeholders are in-place. You need to replace them with the appropriate keys you should receive from bitly.

if this is on purpose for the sake of the question please ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

don't know why but my function "tweetCurrentPage()" for dynamic url won't work it's giving me a respond INVALID_URI from bit.ly, but if I hard code the href value like this twitter.com/share?url=+exemple.com"; it's working...